# Select from x to top/bottom with page up/down on OS X

Tags: macos, mac, finder, highlighting

When I need to highlight a list of items in my explorer on Windows, I was able to select say the 5th item and then hold shift while pressing page end or page down to highlight a number of items. Is there a similar function on OS X?

Answer (score 0):

⇧⇞ and ⇧⇟ do work in some views like most text views, but not in Finder's file browser views.

To select all items from the current item to the end of the view, you can use ⌥⇧↓ in Finder's column view and list view, or ⇧⌘↓ in text views.

I have made ⌥↑, ⌥↓, ⌥⇧↑,  and ⌥⇧↓ move in multiples of eight lines by adding these lines to DefaultKeyBinding.dict:

```
"~\UF700" = (moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp, moveUp);
"~\UF701" = (moveDown:, moveDown:, moveDown:, moveDown:, moveDown:, moveDown:, moveDown, moveDown);
"~$\UF700" = (moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection, moveUpAndModifySelection);
"~$\UF701" = (moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection, moveDownAndModifySelection);
```

The settings don't apply to Finder though.

Answer (score 0):

To highlight eveything to the top of the finder list use: shift + option + up arrow